# How to display blogs related to particular taxonomy term name

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views

I am creating blogs in my site. I have categorized the blogs by using taxonomy terms. I want to display these category names in right side view as a block, and when user clicks on the name, views should display related blogs to the user.
[image]

I tried by using contextual filter but its showing content title not the taxonomy term names, as you can see in the above image right side block.
Below images shows the contextual filter settings i tried.

[image]

[image]

So please help me regarding this.

Comment: Do you want the block to contain all the taxonomy terms for blogs, just the ones with blog activity, or just the ones that are tagging the blog you are viewing? Whether you need a contextual filter or not will depend on this, as well as other details of the block view.

Comment: When the blogs page will get load, i want these categories should be present in the right side block. I am linking these taxonomy terms to blogs by using entity reference field type. So when i click on any one of the taxonomy term from right side block, that related blog should display.

Answer (score 0):

You **don't** need a contextual filter for this. The only thing you need is an **exposed filter** of the **taxonomy** you created. You can then use **Better Exposed Filters** to create links instead of a select list or checkboxes.